# str_extract in R to extract number from a string

Tags: r, stringr

I have a table as below that I would like to extract the number following the underscore

```
 description      desired_output
 desc_lvl1_id_1   1
 desc_lvl1_id_2   2
```

The solution that I have come up with is split into two parts, first to get the underscore and the number that I want, then to take out the underscore gsub("_", "", str_extract(description, "_[0-9]")). I'm hoping though that this can be done in one step

Comment: "following the underscore" could also be "preceding the end of the string" in your example: `str_extract(df$description, "\\d+$")`

Comment: Is the relevant part always at the end? ^^^ yeah boom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a positive lookbehind (`(?<=_)`) and match the numbers that follow the `_` as the `pattern` in `str_extract`.

```
library(stringr)
df1$desired_output <- as.numeric(str_extract(df1$description, '(?<=_)\\d+'))
```